# C++ idiom for loop edges

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, design-patterns

Problem 1: suppose you have an array of n floats and you want to calculate an array of n running averages over three elements. The middle part would be straightforward:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    b[i] = (a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1])/3.
```

But you need to have separate code to handle the cases `i==0` and `i==(n-1)`. This is often done with extra code before the loop, extra code after the loop, and adjusting the loop range, e.g.

```
b[0] = (a[0] + a[1])/2.
for (int i=1; i<n-1; i++)
    b[i] = (a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1])/3.;
b[n-1] = (a[n-1] + a[n-2])/2.
```

Even that is not enough, because the cases of n<3 need to be handled separately.

Problem 2. You are reading a variable-length code from an array (say implementing a UTF-8 to UTF-32 converter). The code reads a byte, and accordingly may read one or more bytes to determine the output. However, before each such step, it also needs to check if the end of the input array has been reached, and if so, perhaps load more data into a buffer, or terminate with an error.

Both of these problems are cases of loops where the interior of the loop can be expressed neatly, but the edges need special handling. I find these sort of problems the most prone to error and to messy programming. So here's my question:
**Are there any C++ idioms which generalize wrapping such loop patterns in a clean way?**

Comment: The simplest way is for the array of moving (not running) averages to have less elements than the inputs (to take into account that, at the edges, you can't calculate the average using the same number of elements - so don't calculate them).   If you need the array of averages to have the same number of elements, you need to make *some* assumptions about the nature of the data  being averaged.

Comment: That's one of several possible solutions (e.g. you can also pad the array, in any of a number of ways), but it's just a simple example. I'm looking for a general approach for this type of problem.

Comment: @Zzyzx - There is not a general approach to this type of problem.   Yes, there are several manners in which padding may be used.    It's also possible to use some form of filtering before computing the moving average.   All approaches involve making some assumptions about characteristics of the input data (or the process that generated it).   But there isn't some universal/general approach that applies in every case.

Comment: Of course. What I am hoping for is some manner of encapsulating the edge behavior in a clear way, while minimizing the possibility of index calculation errors, and generating efficient code.

Comment: I was thinking maybe some generalization of `range`, which would allow for 'fake' iterators beyond the actual existing elements.

Comment: One could overload the `[]` operator to handle out-of-bounds indexes, but this only sugar coats the problem. This is something I have wondered about for decades so I wrote a longer answer.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiently and elegantly handling *boundary conditions* is troublesome in *any* programming language -- C++ has no magic hammer for this. This is a common problem with applying convolution filters to signals / images -- what do you do at the image boundaries where your kernel goes outside the image support?

There are generally two things you are trying to avoid:

- **out of bounds array indexing** (which you must avoid), and
- **special computation** (which is inelegant and results in slower code due to extra branching).

There are usually three approaches:

- **Avoid the boundaries** -- this is the simplest approach and is often sufficient since the boundary case make up a tiny slice of the problem and can be ignored.
- **Extend the bounds of your buffer** -- add extra columns/rows of ***padding*** to the array so the same code used in the general case can be used at the edges. Of course this raises the problem of what values to place in the padding -- this often depends on the problem you are solving and is considered in the next approach.
- **Special computation at the boundary** --  this is what you do in your example. Of course how you do this is problem dependent and raises a similar issue as the previous approach -- what is the correct thing to do when my filter (in your case an averaging filter) extends beyond the array support? What should I consider the values to be outside the array support? Most image filter libraries [provide some form of extrapolation options](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/group__typedefs__npp.html#ga7e1448936057e7401acf293d19278317) -- for example:

  - *assume a value zero or some other constant* (define `a[i] = 0` if `i < 0 || i >= n`),
  - *replicate the boundary value* (e.g. `a[i] = a[0]` if `i < 0` and `a[i] = a[n-1]` if `i >= n`)
  - *wrap the value* (define `a[i] = a[(i + n) % n]` -- makes sense of some cases -- e.g, texture filters)
  - *mirror the border* ((e.g. `a[i] = a[abs(i+1)]` if `i < 0` and `a[i] = a[2n - i -1]` if `i >= n`)
  - *other special case* (what you do)

When reasonable, its best to separate the special case from the general case (like you do) to avoid inelegant and slow general cases. One could always wrap/hide the special case and general case in a function or operator (e.g., *overload* `operator[]`) , but this only sugar coats the problem like any contrived C++ idiom would. In a multi-threaded environment (e.g. CUDA / SIMD) you can do some other tricks be preloading out-of-bounds values, but you are still stuck with the same problem.

This is why programmers use the phrase "edge case" in referring any kind of special case programming and is often a time sink and a source for annoying errors. Some languages that efficiently support *exception handling for out of bounds array indexing* (e.g. Ada) can make for prettier code, but still cause the same pain.

Comment: Thanks, "boundary" would be the better term. In some HPC applications (finite elements?) the boundaries can't be ignored (they are where regions use each other's data) and that's where things can get especially messy. I wonder if there are any metaprogramming tools which handle this in a general way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is NO.
There is no C++ idioms which generalize wrapping such loop patterns in a clean way!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making something like this, but you still need to adjust window size.

```
template <typename T, int N> 
T subscript(T (&data)[N], int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= N) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return data[index];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    b[i] = (subscript(a, i - 1) + subscript(a, i) + subscript(a, i + 1)) / 3.
}
```